# Check if user exists before creating new user djangorestframework

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

So far I have ->

serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer to map the model instance into json format."""
    class Meta:
        """Map this serializer to a model and their fields."""
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username', 'mobile', 'password', 
                  'first_name','last_name','middle_name', 
                  'profile_pic','short_bio','friends_privacy',
                  'address_1','address_2','city',
                  'state','country','pin','verification_code',
                  'is_active','is_blocked','is_reported',
                  'date_created','date_modified')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
        read_only_fields = (
            'date_created', 'date_modified',
            'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 
            'date_joined',)
    def create(self, validated_data):
        mobile_ = validated_data['mobile']
        password_ = validated_data['password']
        username_ = validated_data['username']
        motp = self.context['request'].GET['motp']
        eotp = self.context['request'].GET['eotp']
        email_ = self.context['request'].GET['email']
        mflag = api.views.checkOTP_(mobile_,motp)
        eflag = api.views.checkOTP_(email_,eotp)
        if (mflag and eflag):
            user = User(
            username=username_,
            email =email_,
            password = make_password(password_),
            mobile = mobile_,
            )
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
            return user
```

view:

```
class UserView2(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    model = User

    def get_permissions(self):
        # allow non-authenticated user to create via POST
        return (AllowAny() if self.request.method == 'POST'
                else IsStaffOrTargetUser()),
```

I need to check for OTP of mobile and email and also if a user with same mobile or email already exists.
If user already exists return a json response with error: `already exists!`.
If user is new and OTP is wrong again raise an error.
If user is new and OTP is correct, create an account.

Problem here is I tried to add the function to check for otp verification inside the `def create` `of UserSerializer`. But a serializer is supposed to return the model instance. But if you see the code, I am able to create a user only if OTP is right and user instance is returned. And there is no `else`.

So is there a better way to check for OTP in the view itself?

Answer (score 8):

I don't agree with @Anjaneyulu there..
Serializer handles creation of objects as well.. hence the reason you have `serializer.save()`.

But for the purpose of raising an exception for existing user with same OTP email/phone, you should write your own `def validate_mobile(self, data)` and `def validate_email(self, data)`. DRF serializer will look for these methods in the class first and will run them if they exist. So your custom logic for checking those fields could be:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    def validate_mobile(self, value):
        ModelClass = self.Meta.model
        if ModelClass.objects.filter(mobile=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('already exists')
        return value

    def validate_email_(self, value):
        ModelClass = self.Meta.model
        if ModelClass.objects.filter(email_=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('already exists')
        return value
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            ...,
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct way of implementing it. Serializers are meant only for validation purposes. you should not implement the `create` method in serializer instead write it in `ViewSet`. Creating object is a business logic. It should always go in a `ViewSet`. Write a validation method to the serializer. I'm writing an example code below

serializers.py

```
 class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate_mobile(self, mobile_num):
         is_already_exists = Model.objects.filter(mobile=mobile_num).exists()
         if is_already_exists:
             raise serializers.ValidationError('already exists')
         return mobile_num

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
           'id','username', 'mobile', 'password',
           'first_name','last_name','middle_name','profile_pic',
           'short_bio','friends_privacy','address_1',
           'address_2','city','state','country',
           'pin','verification_code','is_active',
               'is_blocked','is_reported',
           'date_created','date_modified'
       )
       extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
       read_only_fields = (
           'date_created', 'date_modified','is_staff',
           'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'date_joined',
       )
```

Viewsets.py(Business Logic)

```
class UserView2(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        # allow non-authenticated user to create via POST
        return (AllowAny() if self.request.method == 'POST'
                else IsStaffOrTargetUser()),
    def create(self, serializer):
          # your logic goes here.
```

Comment: Won't this interfere in the case of an update if the field is not updated?